# Biblatex: Have only one author in citation -- multiple articles with same first author, different year

Tags: biblatex, author-number

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@article{author99,
title = {A fine title},
year = {1899},
author = {An Author and Another Bauthor and Yeta Cauthor},
journal = {Madness}
}
@article{author05,
title = {The best title},
year = {1905},
author = {An Author and More Dauthors and Whois Thisauthor and Heis Thatauthor},
journal = {Insanity}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[%
  style=authoryear,
  bibstyle=authoryear,
  backend=biber,
  maxbibnames=99,
  maxnames=2,
  firstinits=true,
  uniquename=init]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{test.bib}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\parencite{author99} \\ \parencite{author05}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: output of above code]

As you can see from the image, when the first author is identical, two of the authors are printed in the citation, even if the year of the articles are different. I don't want this, but only the one author, e.g.

```
(Author et al. 1899)
(Author et al. 1905)
```

I've tried setting `maxcitenames=1`, but that didn't make any difference. Is it it possible to achieve this?

Edit:
I'm running TeXlive 2010 on Windows 7, Biblatex version 1.4b with Biber 0.9.

Comment: When I run your example I get your desired result. Can you explain your problem a little bit better?

Comment: @Thorsten: Hmm, I don't.  Could it be related to the version of Biblatex? I have v.1.4b of Biblatex, and Biber 0.9 (if that is relevant).

Comment: I have an old version ob biblatex and biber. I need to update them. Maybe it's because of this.

Comment: I think there is a bit of misunderstanding about the disambiguation features of biblatex 1.4/biber 0.9 - the name and namelist disambiguation is now (correctly) orthogonal to the year disambiguation. Are you really sure you want what you say you want? That looks like exactly the same group of authors wrote two papers, one in 1899 and one in 1905 which isn't accurate. The automatic namelist disambiguation was designed to expand name lists to the minimal point of unambiguity. Of course you can turn it off but do you really want to?

Comment: @PLK: Good point about unambiguity. It's actually too late to change for the project that was the source of the question, but I'll keep it in mind for the future.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The observed behaviour is indeed an effect of the full name (and name list) disambiguation introduced in biblatex v1.4. In your example, you partially disabled name disambiguation with the package option `uniquename=init`, but name *list* disambiguation is still in effect. To achieve the desired behaviour, add the option `uniquelist=false`. See the release notes of biblatex for details and instructive examples.