# Citation style error - Mendeley and LaTex

Tags: biblatex

I have some citation errors using mendeley and latex (texmaker).
I do not know how to explain the errors so I attached the code. Please run it and help if you can.

How to make that:
in text - all the articles to appear "last name et al year" ???
in bibliography - all the authors to appear and the order of the names to be "first - last" ???

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{book}
\usepackage[
 backend=biber,
style=authoryear,
%sorting=none,
maxcitenames=1,
citestyle=authoryear]{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
\begin{document}
\textbf{ERROR In text}:\\

This is good: \cite{Chapman1964}\\

This is not good: \cite{Nie2007}, neither this: \cite{Nie2003}\\
Why do I have more than one name? \textit{\textbf{(1. I want all to be "last name et al." - how to do it?)}}\\

For bibliography errors:\\
\cite{Arrayago2015}\\
\cite{Bursi2005}\\

\textbf{ERROR In bibliography?\\}

1. Why some articles have all the authors and others just the first and "et. al" - see first two. \textit{\textbf{(2. How to modify this to be make all the authors appear in the bibliography?)}}\\

2. Why the first author is "last name - first name" and the others "first name last name"? \textit{\textbf{(3. What should I do make all the articles be "last - first name".)}}

\printbibheading
\printbibliography[type=article, heading=subbibliography,title={Articles}]

\end{document}
```

the bibliography.bib file contains:

```
@article{Chapman1964,
author = {Chapman, JC and Balakrishnan, S},
journal = {The Structural Engineer},
number = {1},
pages = {369--383},
title = {{Experiments on composite beams}},
volume = {42},
year = {1964}
}

@article{Arrayago2015,
author = {Arrayago, I and Picci, F and Mirambell, E and Real, E},
doi = {10.1016/j.tws.2015.02.012},
journal = {Thin-Walled Structures},
pages = {96--107},
title = {{Interaction of bending and axial load for ferritic stainless steel RHS columns}},
volume = {91},
year = {2015}
}

@article{Bursi2005,
author = {Bursi, OS and Sun, FF and Postal, S},
doi = {10.1016/j.jcsr.2004.06.002},
journal = {Journal of Constructional Steel Research},
number = {1},
pages = {67--92},
title = {{Nonlinear analysis of steel concrete composite frames with full and partial shear connection subjected to seismic loads}},
volume = {61},
year = {2005}
}

@article{Nie2007,
author = {Nie, J and Cai, CS and Zhou, TR and Li, Y},
doi = {10.1061/(ASCE)0733-9445(2007)133:4(530)},
journal = {Journal of Structural Engineering},
number = {4},
pages = {530--540},
title = {{Experimental and Analytical Study of Prestressed Steel Concrete Composite Beams Considering Slip Effect}},
volume = {133},
year = {2007}
}

@article{Nie2003,
author = {Nie, J and Cai, CS},
doi = {10.1061/(ASCE)0733-9445(2003)129:4(495)},
journal = {Journal of Structural Engineering},
number = {April},
pages = {495--506},
title = {{Steel Concrete Composite Beams Considering Shear Slip Effects}},
volume = {129},
year = {2003}
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank You!

Comment: Your first complaint looks like something `uniquelist=false` and `uniquename=false` might be able to solve, see also [Set limit to one author when using “et al.” in biblatex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69028/35864) and [Biblatex: Have only one author in citation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17838/35864). The second comes up quite often as well, so much so it is discussed in [Guidelines for customizing biblatex styles](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12806/35864), try `\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}` or `\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{first-last}`.

Comment: Welcome! If the labels in you text are *last name -- year* style, then you need those labels in your bibliography. If the entries there start *first name ...* then how are people supposed to find the entry you are citing?

Comment: Thank you both! I entered maxbibnames=9 and \DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first} in the preamble and all the problems were solved! Thank you again!

Comment: @cfr the problem was that in bibliography the first author was "last name, first name" (so it was possible to find the entry I cited in the text) and 2nd, 3rd ... were "first name, last name". As I said in the previous comment adding \DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first} in the preamble solved the problem! Thank you again!

Comment: Since your questions have essentially been covered before I'm voting to close as a duplicate of [Set limit to one author when using “et al.” in biblatex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69028/35864) (I had to choose, so I went with this one).

Comment: BTW: You might want to consider asking only one question per question in the future so it is easier for us to answer the questions properly.