# Biblatex sees 2 names as 1

Tags: biblatex, biber

For 1 specific citation (and only for that one) with many authors, biblatex keeps on using "author1, author2, et al" even though for everything else it is correctly using only 1 author when there are more than 2 authors (i.e. "author1, et al")

edit: So I've found the culprit. I have two citations with the same first author, and biblatex isn't liking it. Since the publications are on different years though, I'm not sure why this is causing an issue.

MWE:

```
 \documentclass[letterpaper, 10pt]{article}
% Using BIBER
\usepackage[backend=biber,sorting=nyt,style=authoryear,maxnames=2]{biblatex}
\usepackage{placeins}
\addbibresource{bibblio.bib}
\renewcommand{\bibfont}{\small}
\begin{document}
I want to cite \cite{hutter2012starleth} and \cite{hutter2010slip}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

And the bib file is:

```
@book{hutter2012starleth,
  title={StarlETH: A compliant quadrupedal robot for fast, efficient, and versatile locomotion},
  author={Hutter, Marco and Gehring, Michael and Bloesch, Michael and Mark, A Hoepflinger and Remy, C David and Siegwart, Roland Yves},
  year={2012},
  publisher={World Scientific}
}

@inproceedings{hutter2010slip,
  title={Slip running with an articulated robotic leg},
  author={Hutter, Marco and Remy, C David and Hopflinger, MA and Siegwart, Roland},
  booktitle={Intelligent Robots and Systems (IROS), 2010 IEEE/RSJ International Conference on},
  pages={4934--4939},
  year={2010},
  organization={IEEE}
}
```

Comment: Would you mind providing us with an MWE (http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) - complete with this citation, so that we have something to work with? Otherwise it's very difficult to answer this question

Comment: As I mention, I tried making a MWE, but it doesn't reproduce the error...
I can make it anyway, but I'm not sure that it helps...
I can also put a dropbox link with the actual original files, if that perhaps helps more...

Comment: But it would be useful to at least see the citation, maybe any other packages you're using, otherwise there's very little to go on!

Comment: Yeah, wait, I may have found it now (was trying to make the MWE and actually reproduce the error). Give me a moment, and I'll get back

Comment: `uniquenames=false`

Comment: Thanks. Actually the solution was `uniquelist=false`, but your comment pointed me in the correct direction. Also note, it's `uniquename`, without the plural 's'.

Comment: Seems like this is a duplicate of [Set limit to one author when using “et al.” in biblatex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69028/35864) or [Biblatex: Have only one author in citation — multiple articles with same first author, different year](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17838/35864). You could also have a look at `uniquelist=minyear`, please see the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf), pp. 59-60, 237-238 for more details.

Comment: Yeah, at first I had no idea what the problem was, so I didn't know what to search for (see edit). Does seem like a duplicate... what's the policy, should I delete it in this case?

Comment: Good, I have voted to close your question as a duplicate then. There is no need to delete the question, since it remains searchable it might help other people find their way to the answer.