# Strange biblatex behaviour (on sharelatex.com)

Tags: biblatex

The compilation of this tex code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[natbib, maxcitenames=3, style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{bib.bib}
@ARTICLE{G2000,
  author = {{Gondek-Rosi{\'n}ska}, D. and {Bulik}, T. and {Zdunik}, L. and 
    {Gourgoulhon}, E.},
  year = 2000
}
@ARTICLE{G2007,
  author = {{Gondek-Rosi{\'n}ska}, D. and {Bejger}, M. and {Bulik}, T. and 
    {Gourgoulhon}, E.},
  year = 2007
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{bib.bib}

\begin{document}
\citep{G2000}\\
\citep{G2007}\\
\end{document}
```

gives the output of:

(Gondek-Rosińska, Bulik, et al., 2000)

(Gondek-Rosińska, Bejger, et al., 2007)

But when I change the first author's surname to `Gandek-Rosi{\'n}ska` i get the following (desired) output:

(Gandek-Rosińska et al., 2000)

(Gondek-Rosińska et al., 2007)

Actually, changing the name to `Kondek-Rosi{\'n}ska` or any other name works as expected, i.e. gives only the first author name followed by `et al.`. Why such strange behaviour? I compile the code on the [sharelatex.com](http://sharelatex.com).

Comment: In one way it's not strange, it's to emphasize that you're talking about two different groups of authors. Same as in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17838/biblatex-have-only-one-author-in-citation-multiple-articles-with-same-first I guess, so you can try that. `biblatex` and `biber` has undergone a lot of development the last years though, so I'm not completely sure that it still applies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not a bug, but a feature to differentiate between the two publications of the same first author. To disable it, you can set `uniquelist=false`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[natbib, maxcitenames=3, style=authoryear, uniquelist=false]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{bib.bib}
@ARTICLE{G2000,
  author = {{Gondek-Rosi{\'n}ska}, D. and {Bulik}, T. and {Zdunik}, L. and 
    {Gourgoulhon}, E.},
  year = 2000
}
@ARTICLE{G2007,
  author = {{Gondek-Rosi{\'n}ska}, D. and {Bejger}, M. and {Bulik}, T. and 
    {Gourgoulhon}, E.},
  year = 2007
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{bib.bib}

\begin{document}
\citep{G2000}\\
\citep{G2007}\\
\end{document}
```