# Citation the style authoryear APA, problem of listing all authors

Tags: biblatex, apa-style, authoryear, authoryear-icomp

I am using the following package for the citation:

`\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear-icomp ,natbib=true]{biblatex}`

The problem is that while using the commands `\citep` or `\citet`, for articles that have multiple authors, all authors are listed in the citation. For example:

[image: citation example]

Instead, for more than two authors I'd like the citation to look like the following:

[image: correct-citation-example]

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want APA style as mentioned in the title, you should probably load APA style via

```
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa, natbib=true]{biblatex}
```

instead of `style=authoryear-icomp,`. The latter is just a 'generic' author-year style (with ibid. and compressed citations) and not APA.

```
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,companion,worman,geer}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Lorem (Geer, 1985; Goossens et al., 1994; Sigfridsson & Ryde, 1998; Worman, 2002)]

Note that there are some situations where APA style wants more than one author +  et al., namely when two papers with different lists of authors would abbreviate to the same first author + et al.: https://apastyle.apa.org/style-grammar-guidelines/citations/basic-principles/same-year-first-author. `biblatex-apa` implements this rule, so you may occasionally see more than just first author + et al.

---

If you don't want real APA style and can live with a generic author-year, you want to change the value of the `maxcitenames` and `mincitenames` options (see e.g. [biblatex: displaying all authors of multi-author works in the bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1554/35864)).

```
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear-icomp, mincitenames=1, maxcitenames=2]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,companion,worman,geer}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Lorem (Geer 1985; Goossens et al. 1994; Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998; Worman 2002)]

Again, `biblatex` tries to ensure that different lists do not collapse to the same first author + et al., but this feature can be disabled via the `uniquelist` option. See  [Set limit to one author when using "et al." in biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69028/35864) and [Biblatex: Have only one author in citation -- multiple articles with same first author, different year](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17838/35864). A related feature that sometimes throws people off is the `uniquename` feature: [Literature with Biber generates strange citations: firstnames appear erratically](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/91225/35864).

Comment: I would like to thank you very much, your answer is perfect and helpful. Actually, it solved my problem. But I have further questions regarding using \utocite{}  and \cite. It is the first time for me to use \autocite. Can not we use \cite instead of \autocite to produce the same result?

Comment: @Mai `\autocite` is a high-level citation command whose output can be changed with the `autocite` option. In case of the two documents here it basically behaves like `\parencite`. For real APA style you'll want to use `\parencite` and `\textcite` depending on whether you have a parenthetical or narrative citation. I normally prefer not to use `\cite`, but in theory we could redefine `\cite` to do what `\autocite` does. But then you can just do a search-and-replace job in your document and don't need to mess with the definitions.