# Citation should treat authors with the same given name and initials the same (even if one has given their name spelled out in the bib entry)

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing

Similar to [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69028/182643), I would like to limit the author list in a citation to one + et al. (even if the author teams may be different). The proposed solution (`uniquelist=false`) essentially also works, but there is a problem when using it in combination with `citestyle=authoryear-comp`. If in the bibliography, the same (first) author once appears with their given name written out, and once only with their initials, they are not treated as the same author. So in a list of citations, even though `citestyle=authoryear-comp`, the citations will be separated. Here's an example:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
    citestyle=authoryear-comp,
    maxcitenames=1,
    giveninits=true,
    uniquename=init,
    uniquelist=false,
    ibidtracker=context,
 % 
    bibstyle=authoryear,
    dashed=false, % dashed: substitute rep. author with ---
    date=year,
    sorting=nyt,
    minbibnames=3,
    hyperref=true,
    backref=true,
    citecounter=true,
    citetracker=true,
    natbib=true, % natbib compatibility mode (\citep and \citet still work)
    backend=biber, % Compile the bibliography with biber
]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{ABC01,
  author = {Author, A. and Buthor, B. and C},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
@misc{ABC02,
  author = {Author, A. and Buthor, B. and Cuthor, C., and Duthor, D.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Beta},
}
@misc{ADE01,
  author = {Author, Andrew and Duthor, D. and E},
  year = {2001},
  title = {And now for something completely different},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

Some text \citep{ABC01, ABC02, ADE01}.

Some text \autocite{ADE01}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

I tried to fix this behavior by following [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17838/182643) and setting `giveninits=true` and `uniquename=init`, but that did not solve the issue. How can I get `biblatex` to treat *Author, A.* and *Author, Andrew* as the same author?

Answer (score 4):

Starting with `biblatex` v3.20 you can tell `biblatex` to only use initials for hashing, which would be enough here, or you can locally override the name hash with a unique "name ID".

If you want only initials to be used for hashing, go with

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=authoryear-comp,
  maxcitenames=1,
  giveninits=true,
  uniquename=init,
  uniquelist=false,
]{biblatex}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\DeclareNamehashTemplate{
  \namepart[hashscope=full]{family}
  \namepart[hashscope=init]{given}
  \namepart[hashscope=full]{prefix}
  \namepart[hashscope=full]{suffix}
}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{ABC01,
  author = {Author, A. and Buthor, B. and C},
  year   = {2001},
  title  = {Alpha},
}
@misc{ABC02,
  author = {Author, A. and Buthor, B. and Cuthor, C., and Duthor, D.},
  year   = {2001},
  title  = {Beta},
}
@misc{ADE01,
  author = {Author, Andrew and Duthor, D. and E},
  year   = {2001},
  title  = {And now for something completely different},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Some text \autocite{ABC01, ABC02, ADE01}.

Some text \autocite{ADE01}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

If you want to override hashing, go with

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=authoryear-comp,
  maxcitenames=1,
  giveninits=true,
  uniquename=init,
  uniquelist=false,
]{biblatex}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{ABC01,
  author = {id=A1, family=Author, given=A. and Buthor, B. and C},
  year   = {2001},
  title  = {Alpha},
}
@misc{ABC02,
  author = {id=A1, family=Author, given=A. and Buthor, B. and Cuthor, C. and Duthor, D.},
  year   = {2001},
  title  = {Beta},
}
@misc{ADE01,
  author = {id=A1, family=Author, given=Andrew and Duthor, D. and E},
  year   = {2001},
  title  = {And now for something completely different},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Some text \autocite{ABC01, ABC02, ADE01}.

Some text \autocite{ADE01}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

---

## Old answer

You'd need a way to convince `biblatex` that `Author, A.` and `Author, Andrew` are the same person. A workaround is to give a `shortauthor` equal to `Author, A.` for those entries where the `author` is `Author, Andrew`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
  backend=biber, 
  style=authoryear-comp,
  maxcitenames=1,
  minbibnames=3,
  giveninits=true,
  uniquename=init,
  uniquelist=false,
  dashed=false
  date=year,
  backref=true,
  citecounter=true,
]{biblatex}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{ABC01,
  author = {Author, A. and Buthor, B. and C},
  year   = {2001},
  title  = {Alpha},
}
@misc{ABC02,
  author = {Author, A. and Buthor, B. and Cuthor, C., and Duthor, D.},
  year   = {2001},
  title  = {Beta},
}
@misc{ADE01,
  author      = {Author, Andrew and Duthor, D. and E},
  shortauthor = {Author, A. and Duthor, D. and E},
  year        = {2001},
  title       = {And now for something completely different},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

Some text \parencite{ABC01, ABC02, ADE01}.

Some text \autocite{ADE01}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image: Some text (Author et al. 2001a,b,c). Some text (Author et al. 2001c).]

Comment: Hi, thank you! Is this the only way however? I was hoping that this can be done automatically, because manually editing the bibliography entries is not feasible. I have a large bibliography that is also constantly changing (mainly importing from zotero).

Comment: The wanted behavior works with the [A&A journal style](http://ftp.edpsciences.org/pub/aa/aa-package.zip), but they use `natbib` and created a custom function for it I believe.

Comment: @mapf AFAICS a `uniquename` feature that only takes into account initials would need a feature request at https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues

Comment: Ah, that's a shame. But I thought that's what `uniquename=init` is supposed to do? With the settings that I chose, I honestly think it should work the way I expect it. It doesn't really make sense to me that in the citation, `Author et al. 2001c` should be listed separately.

Comment: I think if there are two works by a (first) author with the same family name and initials, it's usually the same person. Two authors sharing the same family name and initials (or even their given name) is an absolute exception. So when the even rarer case happens that you reference them in the same citation you can just address that in the text.

Comment: @mapf Oops, yeah, when I wrote `uniquename` I should have said "name hash". Because the name hashing controls whether or not the names are compressed/dropped.